# Is it possible to get the pool name that is executing an Azure DevOps Pipeline from within the yaml?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

As the title says, is there any way of retrieving the pool name in an azure devops pipeline for use in a script to perform conditional actions based on which pool is used for the pipeline?

I have checked the predefined variables and the list of environment variables in the execution but I cant see the pool name itself specified anywhere.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

> is there any way of retrieving the pool name in an azure devops pipeline for use in a script to perform conditional actions based on which pool is used for the pipeline?

You could use the [Agent variables variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables-devops-services) `Agent.Name` to get the pool name in an azure devops pipeline.

And then you could pass this variable to the script to perform conditional actions, like powershell:

For example:

Variable: `password (secret)`

task: `PowerShell`

Arguments: `-pass $(password)`

Script:

```
Param(
 [String]$pass
)
if ($pass) { Write-Host "variable is NOT null" }
if (!$pass) { Write-Host "variable is null" }
```

Comment: Thank you but isnt that the agent name not the pool name? What I need is the pool name.